# how does ping -W work

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, ping

I want to try to use ping to detect if a server goes down.  So the idea was to have something ping forever, and then if ping ever timed out( -W flag) it would return and I'd be able to detect it.  But if I ping an unreachable address ping just seems to block forever, where i'd expect it to time out and return.

```
ping 1.1.1.1 -W 1 -v
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 9071ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ping` was not blocked, it just didn't showed you the failed transmissions while it was running.

Take a look at the statistics when you stopped it.

```
10 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 9071ms
```

You see packets were transmitted but not received. You ran it for ~10 seconds and it transmitted 10 packets and waited for 1 second for the timeout period you mentioned before sending the next packet.

If you want to visualize the failed transmissions you can use the `-f` option with a suitable ping interval using the option `-i interval`. The value of `interval` should be greater than 0.2 seconds. You can find more details of it the manual page of ping by running `man ping`.

```
ping -f -i .5 -W 1 1.1.1.1
```

Will produce an output like this.

```
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
.......^C
--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3048ms
```

Where each `.` represents a transmission without any reply and in case of a reply one backspace will be printed removing a `.`.

I think [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/simple-linux-and-unix-system-monitoring-with-ping-command-and-scripts.html) is the kind of solution you are looking for. An automated script for periodically checking the connectivity.